# Creating roles does not work | discord.js v13

Tags: discord.js

Using

```
            message.guild.roles.create({
               data: {
                   name: `xyz`,
                   color: '#FFFFFF',
                   mentionable: true
               } 
            });
```

This does not seem to work and just returns `undefined` any idea why?

Comment: Are you resolving the promise that `create()` returns?

Answer (score 1):

Please, as much as possible, read the documentation. It seems like you're using the version 12 counterpart of the RoleManager method - https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/RoleManager?scrollTo=create?

Therefore, the correct *v13* way to do this is remove the data property, and hoist all options to the method *itself*:

```js
guild.roles.create({
  name: 'Super Cool Blue People',
  color: 'BLUE',
  reason: 'we needed a role for Super Cool People',
})
```

...since now, the current version *just* accepts an `options` object that's supposed to contain the necessary fields.

Resource(s): https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/CreateRoleOptions / https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/RoleManager?scrollTo=create.

Comment: Does not work, Still returns `undefined`

Comment: Did you try doing what @Elitezen said?